# Switch case statement

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an application in **C#** that converts numbers in a text box to roman numerals in a label control and need to use a case statement. However one of my variable **Roman** gets the error message: Use of unassigned local variable 'Roman'.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Roman_Numeral_Converter
 {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {   
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int Number=int.Parse(txtNum.Text); // To hold Number
        string Roman; // To hold Roman Numeral 

        if (Number>=1 && Number <=10)
        {
            switch (Roman)
            {
                case "Number==1":
                lblRoman.Text = "I";
                break;
                case "Number==2":
                lblRoman.Text = "II";
                break;
                case "Number==3":
                lblRoman.Text = "III";
                break;
                case "Number==4":
                lblRoman.Text = "IV";
                break;
                case "Number==5":
                lblRoman.Text = "V";
                break;
                case "Number==6":
                lblRoman.Text = "VI";
                break;
                case "Number==7":
                lblRoman.Text = "VII";
                break;
                case "Number==8":
                lblRoman.Text = "VIII";
                break;
                case "Number==9":
                lblRoman.Text = "IX";
                break;
                case "Number==10":
                lblRoman.Text = "X";
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Invalid Input");
        }

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the form.
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNum.Text = "";
        lblRoman.Text = "";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `case "Number==1":` should be like `case 1:` and the same for the rest of the cases and the variable `Roman` should be initialized before being used.

Comment: Read: http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch

Comment: You haven't assigned any value to your variable Roman,also the use of switch is not right

Comment: If this isn't homework or you aren't required to use `switch`, I would  consider a different design for this task.

Answer (score 3):

Your structure is a little off.

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var Number = int.Parse(txtNum.Text); // To hold Number

    switch (Number)
    {
            case 1:
              lblRoman.Text = "I";
              break;
            case 2:
              lblRoman.Text = "II";
              break;
            case 3:
              lblRoman.Text = "III";
              break;
            case 4:
              lblRoman.Text = "IV";
              break;
            case 5:
              lblRoman.Text = "V";
              break;
            case 6:
              lblRoman.Text = "VI";
              break;
            case 7:
              lblRoman.Text = "VII";
              break;
            case 8:
              lblRoman.Text = "VIII";
              break;
            case 9:
              lblRoman.Text = "IX";
              break;
            case 10:
              lblRoman.Text = "X";
              break;
            default:
              MessageBox.Show("Error: Invalid Input");
              break;
    }

}
```

You're using the `lblRoman` to hold your result, thus your `Roman` variable is unnecessary.  Additionally, since you're interrogating every possible valid number in your `switch`, you can just use the `default` to replace your `if`/`else` structure.

I'm assuming you're doing this as an academic exercise.  That being said, I would be remiss not to point to you [Mosè Bottacini's solution to this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11749642/1497479)

Comment: There is already a value for roman listed under my click event.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

when your number value like `1` so roman number is `I`.

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int Number = int.Parse(txtNum.Text); // To hold Number
        string Roman; // To hold Roman Numeral

        if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 10)
        {
            switch (Number)
            {
                case 1:
                    lblRoman.Text = "I";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    lblRoman.Text = "II";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    lblRoman.Text = "III";
                    break;

                case 4:
                    lblRoman.Text = "IV";
                    break;

                case 5:
                    lblRoman.Text = "V";
                    break;

                case 6:
                    lblRoman.Text = "VI";
                    break;

                case 7:
                    lblRoman.Text = "VII";
                    break;

                case 8:
                    lblRoman.Text = "VIII";
                    break;

                case 9:
                    lblRoman.Text = "IX";
                    break;

                case 10:
                    lblRoman.Text = "X";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Invalid Input");
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `switch (Number)` not `switch (Roman)` as Roman is not initialized or even used.

Comment: That doesnt work because you can't implicitly convert int to string and also then when they enter the numbers 1-10 into the text box it wont show up as the corresponding roman numeral

Comment: check i have update my answer. when your text value 1-10 so it's return roman value in your `lblRoman.Text`.

Comment: To fix it I had to have switch (Roman=Number) if anybody else has same problem.

Comment: what you want i am not able to understand. and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Roman variable is really unassigned. You should assign it before you enter the statement

Comment: Clarification this is homework so i have to use switch case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `switch`, You can do other way using `Linq` which is even better.

```
int Number=int.Parse(txtNum.Text);
var romanList = new List<string> {"I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X"};
if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 10)
lblRoman.Text = romanList.Select((r, i) => new { Roman = r, Index = i+1}).FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Index == Number).Roman;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your switch statement this way. and of course you need to assign a variable before using it.

```
public string GetNum(string val)
{
    string res = ""; // Assign it an empty string. 
    var numToRom = new Dictionary<string, string>
                       {
                           {"1","I"},
                           {"2","II"}
                           //so on
                       };

        numToRom.TryGetValue(val, out res);
        return res;
}
```