# I am trying to code for problem to convert Integer to roman numbers using enumerations i am unable to get for numbers above 10

Tags: c#, enums, roman-numerals

```
public string IntToRoman(int num)  {
   while(num >= 10)
    {
        for(int i = num ; num >= 10 ; i= i/10)
        { 
            if(i<= num)
            {
                var Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(RomanToInt), i*10); 
                a= a+""+Name; 
                
             }  
            num=  num % j - num % (j / 10);
            i = num;
        }
    }
   
    if(num < 10)
    {
         for(int i = 0 ; i <= num ; i++)
            {   
                 if(num < 5)
                 {
                    var Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(RomanToInt), 1);
                    b = b+""+Name; 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    var Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(RomanToInt), 5);
                    b = b+""+Name; 
                    num=  num - 5;
                   }
      }
    }
   s=a+""+b;
   return s;   
}
```

Comment: What's your definition of `RomanToInt`? Please see [ask]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting integers to roman numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040289/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals)